# CMOS (or CMOS compatible) shift register with latched open-drain outputs

Tags: digital-logic, cmos, ttl

I've been looking for a 3.3V compatible shift register (SIPO) with latched open-drain outputs. I've settled on a 74xx596 (not a '595!), but of all the 74xx CMOS series I've been looking at omit this one. Any idea on why? and if it's possible to get CMOS variants of these, because of the open-drain outputs?

Correction: I was getting confused between 595 and 596. 595 has tri-state outputs, 596 has open collector outputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm playing around with TI's [TLC5925](http://focus.ti.com/docs/prod/folders/print/tlc5925.html), which is functionally very similar to what you're asking for. It is designed for driving LED's at a constant current, and the logic is 3.3/5V CMOS. The output is tolerant of up to 17V, although I don't know how well it would drive the outputs to logic levels. Not sure if this is suitable - just taking a wild guess at your intended application.

Answer (score 3):

595 does not have OD outputs - 74HC595 is very common. Ti do a high-power open-drain one [TPIC6595](http://focus.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=tpic6595&fileType=pdf&track=no)

Comment: I'm getting confused with the 595 and 596 - it's the 596 which has open collector/open drain.