# Drive Fight on 7400 Series

Tags: driver, ttl, output, tri-state, 74hc595

I'm currently designing a 7400 series circuit to drive LEDs from a set of shift registers (74595).  Each shift register's tri-state input is wired to the output of a 2:4 decoder (74139), and the decoder's input is driven by a 4 bit counter (74191).  The counter has a 200Hz clock input.

In steady state, this circuit runs fine.  My concern is during the transition. According to the 74LS139 and 74HC595 datasheets, the decoder will transition from one output state to another faster than the tri-state output of the shift registers.  This means that there is a brief period of time (about 10ns) where both shift registers will drive their outputs before they complete their transition.

My question is, will this brief transitional period damage and eventually destroy the shift registers?  I've attached a simplified schematic illustrating my question.
[image: Can the drive fight damage the shift registers?]

Do note that this is a simplified schematic.  The real circuit has **way** more shift registers.  As such, multiplexing each shift register is prohibitive (I would need a 96:32 multiplexer, a.k.a. lots and lots of 7400 series parts).

Comment: I hope the real circuit has a resistor in series with each LED?

Comment: Tying two outputs that both drive high and low together like that is  bad idea.  What is supposed to happen when the two outputs disagree?

Comment: @Olin : what is so bad about tristate logic?

Comment: @Wouter: Yes it does: I forgot to put it in the schematic.  But thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Brian: Nothing. Are those tri-state gates? I can barely read the part value on the schematic and didn't look it up in any case. If the issue is gates fighting each other when transitioning between full drive and tri-state at a clock edge, then that shouldn't destroy anything due to the very brief time, but will cause power current glitches with possibly unexpected results. Put a resistor in each line to be safe. Delete R1 and split it into two resistors, one for each line. Why isn't there a microcontroller doing all this instead of a mess of discrete logic in the first place though?

Comment: @Olin: I apologize for the small image.  You can see a larger version here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/W041X.png

Comment: @Olin: Yes, a microcontroller would be so much easier, but this is an entry for a 7400 logic contest.  I think using an uC in this case would be cheating?

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but if you wanted to reduce component count, you could eliminate R1 and R2, put Q1 collector straight to Vcc, and put D1 and an appropriate resistor between Q1 emitter and ground. Assuming you just forgot to draw a resistor in series with D1, this saves you two resistors per LED.

Comment: @TRIS: You could implement a microcontroller in 7400 logic, then do your project the easy way by programming the microcontroller ;-)

Comment: @Olin: My mind just exploded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a problem provided you aren't switching between the shift registers at silly speeds (MHz instead of kHz). I base this on:

1. the 10ns overlap is between typical \$t(en)=15ns\$ and \$t(dis)=23ns\$ on the 595 datasheet. So it's less than half the turn-off times. I doubt that the drivers will both be fully on during this overlap.
2. Drive strength (to the TI datasheet) is guaranteed 6ma, quite low. Worst case drive current will be several times this figure - maybe 25ma at 5V, 0.125W * 8 (no. of outputs). A permanent short circuit may eventually destroy the drivers through overheating, but:
3. The duty cycle and thus the excess heating is quite low: 10ns per (insert your switching period) - multiply the power above by this (rather small) number.

Finally, if you are still worried about this, you could use OEn on the 74139 decoder to disable both 595s during such transitions.

Comment: With regard to your last point, depending upon the nature of CLK_STRB, one may be able to use it to gate the encoder so that it would be disabled while the output-select was being changed.

Comment: @Supercat : that thought occurred to me. Only the questioner knows enough context to say, but if true, it would be a simple way of making the switching safer.

Comment: I have thought about this, but CLK_STRB has a 50% duty cycle.  As such, wiring it to the OE pin of the decoder will turn the LED on for half the time, thus making it dimmer.  It's too bad really, because it would be an easy way to make me sleep better at night.

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution: instead of having one R1 per driving transistor, put R1 on the output of each shift register. Then the maximum current that can flow between two shift registers is limited by 2x 47k resistors, but the drive path between shift register and transistor is the same.

(I'm not sure if the 10ns shoot-through would actually be a problem, but given the amount of discrete logic it's worth considering what happens if part of it fails and two shift registers get stuck on)

Comment: +1 for identifying the failure condition of both outputs stuck on.

Comment: It's a nonexistent condition unless you destroy the 2:4 line decoder first.

Comment: @pjc50: That's a pretty neat idea, actually.  It increases the the number of parts, but resistors are very cheap.  Thanks for the great suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a shift register with open drain/collector outputs so they simply can't fight each other. See [CMOS (or CMOS compatible) shift register with latched open-drain outputs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6681/cmos-or-cmos-compatible-shift-register-with-latched-open-drain-outputs)

Comment: It's too bad that 74596 ICs are so hard to find: it would otherwise be a great solution.